# Grails cast sqltype "number" to String

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an abstract `Event` class which holds properties shared by all Event types and beneath it I have two subclasses with one table per class (`MasterEvent` and `ParentEvent`).

The problem is that in `MasterEvent` the id column is of type "number" and in the `ParentEvent` it is of type "varchar2".
This means that when I try to run the app I get :

> Caused by HibernateException: Wrong column type in * for column event_id. Found: number, expected: varchar2(255 char).

Note that this is a legacy database, so there's no chance in changing the column types on the database level.

The sample code below should help in understanding better:

**Event.groovy**

```
package a

abstract class Event {
    String id

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy "false"
        id column: "id"
    }
}
```

**ParentEvent.groovy**

```
package a

class ParentEvent extends Event {
    static mapping = {
        id column: "id"
    }
}
```

**MasterEvent.groovy**

```
package a

class MasterEvent extends Event {
    static mapping = {
        id column: "id", type: "number"
    }
}
```

I have tried putting `type: number` all sorts of combinations, but it's always giving me the same error.

Is there anyway to either cast the `sqlType` directly to `String` or have grails ignore this validation?

Comment: Is there any answer to this yet?

Answer (score 1):

`type: 'number'` does not work because it is not a [hibernate basic type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes)

Try changing it to `type: 'long'` (or whatever fits your legacy DB)

Also see the docs: [Link](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#ormdsl)

---

*Edit after your comment*

I don't know what you are doing in your abstract class, but perhaps you can do something like that and use the getter in your abstract class (not tested!):

```
class MasterEvent extends Event {

    Long longId        
    static mapping = {
        longId column: "id"
    }

    @Override
    String getId() {
        longId?.toString()
    }   
}
```

Comment: I have tried with type: 'long' and 'big_integer' with no success (always with the same error)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to define id field in subclasses? "String id" in Parent event and "long id" in Master event?

Comment: Yep, if i do this, it either: a) complains about the other one being "String", or b) Says that the return types are incompatible (which i find odd, because i recall that java.lang.Long can be cast to java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a custom [Hibernate UserType](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customHibernateTypes) which takes the number id column and converts it to a String.  This would then go in the MasterEvent class:

```
static mapping = {
    id column: "id", type: NumberToStringType
}
```